# How to match a part of string before a character into one variable and all after it into another

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a problem with splitting string into two parts on special character.

For example:

```
12345#data
```

or

```
1234567#data
```

I have 5-7 characters in first part separated with `"#"` from second part, where are another data (characters,numbers, doesn't matter what)

I need to store two parts on each side of `#` in two variables:

```
x = 12345
y = data
```

without `"#"` character.

I was looking for some Lua string function like `splitOn("#")` or substring until character, but I haven't found that.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Though they look similar, Lua pattern isn't regex, please don't add the *regex* tag back.

Comment: People who regex, also might know Lua patterns, thus it makes no sense removing regex tag. Adding lua-patterns tag is alright.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's not what tags should do. I'll say it one more time: **Lua pattern isn't regex**. A question with *regex* tag would confuse people that a solution using regex would be a valid answer to this question, but that's not true.

Comment: Oh, so should we start thinking of tags for JS-regex, Python-regex, net-regex...? Look at Vim, is it *regex*? But all questions are tagged regex. Also, regular expressions are not regular any more. And when a `.` means *match any character* that is already a regex, not a wildcard. Just another flavor. Besides, you are not consistent then. Why not go and remove `regex` tag from all Lua questions asking for help with `regex`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, that's not what I said, and you clearly don't have a full understanding of Lua patterns, please read [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html).  Lua pattern matching isn't some extension to regex, as the regex in other languages/tools. As a simple example, try [`print(string.match("ababab","(ab)+"))`](http://ideone.com/Aa11RR) in Lua, it's not working as you might expect, e.g, [the result in Ruby](http://ideone.com/XonHM4).

Comment: The rollback war on this question is under discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316309/a-rollback-war-about-regex-tag) on meta.

Comment: It is unfortunate this post led to such a firestorm over the tag, when it fact it's just not a good, well-researched question and should be closed. [This search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blua%5D+split+string) turned up as the first hit a thorough discussion of various techniques for splitting strings in Lua. There is nothing in this question that suggests the OP needs anything more than that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `string.match` and captures.
Try this:

```
s = "12345#data"
a,b = s:match("(.+)#(.+)")
print(a,b)
```

Comment: The `(.+)#(.+)` pattern is rather inefficient compared to a negated character class solution. Since `.` matches `#`, too, there are a lot of backtracking steps that do not take place when using a mere `[^#]+` that matches chunks without checking if we have `#`, backtrack, check, backtrack.... until it checks through all your string. If a regex seems "easy" it does not mean it is efficient. Also, with capturing groups, you are limited to a string with just 2 chunks, what about `12#34#56`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, all valid points, thanks. Achoring the pattern as in `^(.+)#(.+)$` helps performance a lot, though it probably does not matter in this example.

Answer (score 12):

See [this documentation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin):

> First of all, although Lua does not have a split function is its standard library, it does have `string.gmatch`, which can be used instead of a split function in many cases. Unlike a split function, `string.gmatch` takes a pattern to match the non-delimiter text, instead of the delimiters themselves

It is easily achievable with the help of a *negated character class* with `string.gmatch`:

```
local example = "12345#data"
for i in string.gmatch(example, "[^#]+") do
  print(i)
end
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jpQbKS)

The `[^#]+` pattern matches one or more characters other than `#` (so, it "splits" a string with 1 character).

Comment: Note that a negated character class is formed with `[^` followed with the characters/shorthand constructs/POSIX character classes and closed with `]`.